# Posts on my page not displaying after live

Tags: wordpress, blogs, posts

I am having my site in wordpress, it works perfectly before it is live.
But after it is Live My blog posts not appearing

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Is not working, in my single.php.
What i need to do?
what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  
  echo get_the_content();  
 endwhile;   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One

Fetch All Post

```
<?php  
    $myposts = get_posts();

    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></a>

    <?php endforeach; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

you also pass argument on

Particular Category Post Fetch

```
<?php

$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts();

foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></a>

        <?php endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```